# how to repeat option between a range in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to print 2014-2050 in angular js. I have tried to find it in google and SO and i got below

```
<select class="form-control" >
<option  ng-repeat="n in [2014,2015,2016, .. 2050]" value="{{n}}">
    {{n}}
</option>                               
</select>
```

I am currently learning angular js. 
I want to run a loop between a defined range?
like in php if i want to run a loop between 2014-2050 the i will do this

```
for($i=2014;$i<=2050;$i++)
{
  echo $i;
}
```

How can i run the above for loop in angular js.
Please help me.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please elaborate your query?

Comment: Just by the way, you can use `ngOptions` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select in the select, instead of the `ngRepeat`.

Comment: This question is not duplicate of any of these SO. And these answers are not correct answer. Thanxs for helping me.

Comment: Can you clarify in your question how it's different to the possible duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably best to initialise the array of dates in the controller (or even better, in a service), and then loop over the pre-created array in the template. So in the controller:

```
$scope.dates = [];

var initDates = function() {
  var i;
  for (i = 2014;i <= 2050; i++) {
    $scope.dates.push(i);
  }
}

initDates();
```

And then in the template:

```
ng-repeat="date in dates"
```

Which can be seen at http://plnkr.co/edit/9K9VhAAM9HxopDlCVLi9?p=preview

Comment: I have seen this in SO. But i don't think it is a correct process.

Comment: Can you clarify why you don't think it's correct?

Comment: before making down vote, please clarify

Comment: @FizerKhan I can't vote down.

Comment: i am trying to find is there any other way to do this. Because this is a lengthy process

Answer (score 2):

You have to create range in your controllers and use either `ng-repeat` or `ng-options`. `ng-options` is better.

**JS**

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    var years = [];
    for (var i = 2014; i <= 2050; i++) {
       years.push(i);
    }
    $scope.years = years;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" >
    <option  ng-repeat="year in years" value="{{year}}">
        {{n}}
    </option>
</select>
```

(or) You can use ng-options

```
<select ng-model="selectedYear" ng-options="year for year in years"></select>
```

Comment: Before making down vote, please clarify

Answer (score 0):

Its not mentioned in the angular docs, but you can use the `limitTo` filter twice to slice a range in a array/object.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo

Its as simple as this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:10 | limitTo:-5">{{item}}</li>
```

working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/8LXXnH?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

use the custom Filters here.

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Main">
    <li ng-repeat="date in [] | range:2050">{{date}}</li>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.filter('range', function() {
  return function(input, total) {
    total = parseInt(total);
    for (var i=2014; i<=total; i++)
      input.push(i);
    return input;
  };
});
```